# Ubuntu Server IP Static error to restart with ifdown and RTNETLINK: file exists

Tags: networking, server, static-ip, ip-address

I gave static IP on ubuntu server, by adding the IP configuration in /etc/network/interfaces

the contents is

```
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  # Static IP to eth0
  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.20.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.20.255
  dns-nameservers 202.158.3.7 8.8.8.8
```

and I am configurations DNS in /etc/resolv.conf

the contents is

```
  # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
  #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
  nameserver 127.0.1.1 
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

and i am configuration in /etc/hosts

```
  127.0.0.1     localhost
  192.168.20.2  user #IP Address for eth0 

  # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
  ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  fe00::0 ip6-localnet
  ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
  ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2 ip6-allrouter
```

when i restart the configuration error

```
  $ sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
    ifdown: interface eth0 not configured 
    RTNETLINK: file exists
    Failed to bring up eth0
```

And I restart the configuration again with the command

```
    $ sudo service networking restart
      stop: Job failed while stopping
      start: Job is already running: networking
```

I restart again with command

```
    $ sudo service network-manager restart
      network-manager: unrecognized service
```

I don't know why, please help me

Comment: run this command `sudo dhclient eth0 -r` see if that dose any thing.

Answer (score 0):

First off you have an illegal gateway.  You can't have a real machine with the address `*.*.*.255`.  Second thing I notice is that you failed to indent your lines. The contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` should read (replace `192.168.20.254` with your real gateway address):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Static IP to eth0
auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.20.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.20.254
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

After you make that change, reboot the system (this will negate any issues with services failing to restart).  You should be good to go then.

Comment: Good catch on the illegal gateway address - but why duplicate it in your answer? AFAIK indentation isn't significant.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for your respon. Sorry, there are some wrong when I want to ask, I have revision my question,  can be assisted back, why the error?

Comment: Oh wow, good catch @steeldriver, I can't believe I missed that...

Comment: Have you tried editing the `/etc/hosts` file like I suggested and rebooting the whole system?